# Start Macbook with lid closed

Tags: macbook, external-display

I want to use my Macbook (early 2010) lid-closed with external monitor, keyboard and mouse. 
Is it possible to start it lid closed? For example to use it in a [Henge Docks station](http://hengedocks.com/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If your Mac has been shut down:**

You will need to use the power button to start it if it's been shut down completely. Only older Macs like the G3s had a power button on their keyboards, but this was removed – possibly because such a thing was never intended use for USB.

**If your Mac was put to sleep:**

To wake up a MacBook from sleep and run it in [closed clamshell mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131), all you need is to press a button on a connected keyboard or mouse to wake it up again.* Obviously, this works immediately (and without setup) for wired devices. For wireless keyboards and mice, you will need to pair them *before* you put the MacBook to sleep.

Given that you somehow need to control the machine, it's very likely that this will suffice in your case. Additionally, simply connecting a USB device will also do the same – at least in most cases.

<sub>* In OS X Lion, even closing the lid is enough, but in your case – with a docking station – you can't attach the external display before you close the lid, so this is not possible here.</sub>

Comment: TIL Macs don't have any way to power them on without opening the lid, ouch.  That's one point in favor of a traditional docking station (they usually have a power button).

Answer (score 0):

If your MB is plugged into a wired network, you can use 'wake on lan' functionality, and I believe there are iPhone apps for this as well.

Comment: Start != wake..