# Powering up a MacBook Pro using external keyboard or mouse

Tags: macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start Macbook with lid closed](https://superuser.com/questions/396335/start-macbook-with-lid-closed)

Is there a way to power on a MacBook pro via a USB keyboard or mouse, similar to waking it from sleep?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the machine is in [clamshell mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131) (with display and power connected), a USB keyboard or mouse will wake it.  Otherwise, @SimonSheehan is correct - USB will be powered down.